# Why when I rebase my feature branch to develop result in detached head?

Tags: git, version-control, rebase

I'm on my feature branch that was created from candidate/2.11.00 and want to rebase it to new version.

```
git rebase candidate/2.12.00
```

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Upstream is not set.
could not detach HEAD
```

Comment: What does `git branch -vv` show you?  Is the `candidate/2.11.00` branch tracking any upstream?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, result of git branch -vv  `candidate/2.11.00                                    a407edb [origin/candidate/2.11.00: behind 17] fix render change`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebase works *by* detaching HEAD, then doing a series of `git cherry-pick` commands or equivalent to *copy* some set of commits, then moving the old branch name—the one that `HEAD` was attached to at the start—to the last copied commit.

If the rebase has to stop before completely succeeding, you are left in this detached-HEAD mode.  You should either finish the rebase with however much manual work is required, or revoke it entirely (e.g., `git rebase --abort`).  That will put things right, where *right* is defined by what you commanded (finish, or stop trying).

That's the answer to the question you asked.  The question that maybe you *should* ask is why your rebase was unable to *start:*

> ```
> First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
> Upstream is not set.
> could not detach HEAD
> ```

The "Upstream is not set" message is odd.  There are no occurrences of this exact string in current Git, and there is no reason for the command `git rebase candidate/2.12.00` to need to look up the upstream of the current branch in the first place.

The "could not detach HEAD" error occurs when a `git checkout --detach` (or internal equivalent) fails.  It would fail when there are fundamental permissions issues inside your Git repository, or when your computer's file system has gone into a frozen / read-only mode—Linux does this after certain disk drive failures, for instance—or if you have a badly configured Windows Antivirus system that is preventing you from doing any work.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the problem was in post-checkout hook that should make git pull after each checkout. And when upstream not set exit with code 1. Which terminated git rebase. Once I changed exit code to 0, rebase  started to work ok.